# Si quiero hacer un array de booleanos que se llama nuevoArray que tenga un rango desde los -10000 hasta los 10000, como podria hacerlo?

Tags: java, array, booleano

Aca dejo el array booleano del cual quero delimitar el rango de entre `-10.000` a `10.000`

```
boolean nuevoArray [] = new boolean [???];
```

Comment: Lamentablemente, los arreglos no pueden tener índices negativos en java. Lo más que podrás hacer es una clase que lo simule, pero no podrás usar la sintaxis de `nuevoArray[-10]`. Java no admite la sobrecarga de operadores.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes hacerlo. Los índices en los arrays no admiten rangos negativos. Lo que puedes hacer es crear un array con 20001 valores (20001 apegándome estrictamente al rango que has puesto en la pregunta) y a la hora de mostrarlos, a través de código,  simules que los primeros 10000 son negativos y los restantes positivos.

Comment: Desde los -10000 hasta los 10000 no serían acaso 20001 valores?

Comment: Vamos a ver, diciendo que fuera posible ese rango, sí, la cantidad de valores posibles a setear serían 20001